# ¿Por qué "estar en un buen fregado" es "estar en problemas"?

Tags: etimología, expresiones, coloquialismos

La expresión "estar en un buen fregado" (también "meterse en un buen fregado") significa estar (o meterse) en problemas. En la entrada del DEL para "[fregado](https://dle.rae.es/fregado?m=form)" vemos las acepciones coloquiales

> 9. m. coloq. Enredo, embrollo, negocio o asunto poco decente.

> 10. m. coloq. Lance, discusión o contienda desordenada en que puede haber algún riesgo imprevisto.

Aunque no se recoge la locución "estar en un fregado" de manera explícita, se infiere de esas acepciones.

¿Cómo ha llegado "fregado" a adquirir estos significados coloquiales? Dado que algo que está "fregado" está limpio (y terminado) no consigo ver la relación con estar o meterse en un asunto turbio o una discusión. Lo más que se me ocurre, en relación al tema, es pisar un suelo que esté recién fregado (que puede ser peligroso para quien lo pisa, por ser resbaladizo, y molesto para el que lo ha fregado, porque le estropean el trabajo hecho). Pisar un suelo fregado puede ser "meterse en una situación delicada", pero de ahí pasar a "meterse en una discusión" puede ser un poco un ejercicio de autocomplacencia (a no ser que digamos que nos viene una bronca del que fregó el suelo).

¿Puede alguien confirmar o arrojar un poco de luz sobre este coloquialismo - y corroborar o rectificar mi mera suposición sobre el posible origen del término?

Comment: En Chile no se usa de esa forma. Nosotros decimos _estoy fregado_, _me fregaste_. Significa "dar por perdido", "fallar", "hacer fallar", "estropear". Se usa bastante, reemplazando a _cagar_, que significa lo mismo pero es una grosería. Yo creo que la expresión chilena deriva de _refriega_ (que es una "pelea").

Comment: @Rodrigo Interesante. Consideré ponerle la etiqueta de España a la pregunta, porque no estaba seguro de que "estar en un (buen) fregado" fuese una expresión usada en todos los países hispanohablantes. Veremos qué aportan usuarios de otros países. Quizá esta expresión también viene de algún término que suene similar, como el "refriega" que tú aportas.

Comment: A mí me resulta obvio su significado de meterse en un asunto que se debería evitar ¿a quién no le ha pasado que sin darse cuenta, se ha metido en un suelo recién fregado? Lo de resbalar es posible, pero el  problema de verdad es la bronca que te puedes llevar. Instintivamente acabas evitando el suelo fregado, para no ganarte una sarta de merecidos improperios.

Comment: Autoridades, 1732: "Muger de buen _fregado_. Se llama la que es de buen rostro y tiene desembarazo y despéjo." "Éramos tres hermanas, buenas mozas y de buen fregado", Francisco López de Úbeda, _La pícara Justina_, 1605 (España). No tiene nada que ver pero me pareció interesante comentarlo.

Comment: @charlie Interesante. Hay alguna manera fácil de saber a qué se refiere "desembarazo y despéjo"? Lo primero asumo que puede ser tanto que no tiene hijos como que tiene soltura o comodidad en ciertas cosas. Si quieres lo planteo como una pregunta nueva tipo "por qué se dice/decía que una mujer 'de buen fregado' era XYZ" o qué quieren decir estos adjetivos en esta entrada del diccionario".

Comment: A mí también me dejaron algo perplejo esos adjetivos, aunque entiendo que la respuesta la podremos encontrar igualmente en el _Autoridades_.

Comment: @Charlie Pues lo publico como nueva pregunta, porque me parece interesante y será más fácil de encontrar para el resto de la comunidad que enterrado bajo el séptio comentario a una pregunta todavía sin respuesta. En cuanto saque un minuto (que se me acaban de despertar ambos niños) la hago.

Comment: @charlie hecho: [¿Qué es una mujer “de buen fregado” - desembarazada y con despéjo?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/35155/5481)

Comment: Yo también creo que el *fregado* de esta expresión viene de refriega, pero no tengo ningún documento en que basarme, así que lo dejo solo como comentario.

Answer (score 1):

En mi opinión, se ralaciona con el hecho de que *fregar* implica *restregar*, *frotar con fuerza*, *desgastar*. Algo parecido a la palabra *refregar*.
En México *fregar* es una de esa palabras que se usan para todo y tiene muchos significados: estropear, fastidiar, perjudicar, timar, etc.

- Estoy *fregado*  (no tengo esperanza / estoy enfermo / estoy en problemas)
- Ya me *fregué* ( estoy arruinado )
- Me lo *fregué* en el fútbol ( le gané )
- No me *frieges* ( no me molestes )
- Se me *fregó* el carro ( se estropeó )
- Anoche me *fregaron* ( me robaron / golpearon / timaron )
- ¡Ah *fregado*! ( no me lo creo / me sorprende )
- Tiene un *friego* de dinero ( tiene mucho dinero )
- Te ves de la *fregada* ( te ves mal )

Quizá la riqueza de *fregar* se deba a que tiene un sonido muy cercano a *chingar*. De hecho, en México, las palabras son intercambiables pero *fregar* es aceptada en círculos mas amplios.