# ¿Qué es una mujer "de buen fregado" - desembarazada y con despéjo?

Tags: significado, definiciones, adjetivos, palabras-raras

En [¿Por qué “estar en un buen fregado” es “estar en problemas”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/35142/5481) aportaba Charlie en un comentario

> Autoridades, 1732: **"Muger de buen fregado. Se llama la que es de buen rostro y tiene desembarazo y despéjo."** "Éramos tres hermanas, buenas mozas y de buen fregado", Francisco López de Úbeda, La pícara Justina, 1605 (España)

De estas tres cualidades, la primera (tener buen rostro) creo que nos queda clara a todos. Las otras dos "tener desembarazo y despéjo" ya son menos claras. No sé si tener "desembarazo" es algo como "tener sonrojo", vergüenza o algo similar. Sobre "despéjo" pues ya ni idea.

¿Puede alguien aclarar el significado de estos dos adjetivos que califican a la "mujer de buen fregado" para que entendamos qué se entendía en 1732 por esta calificación?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El [Diccionario de la lengua española](https://www.rae.es/) de la Real Academia Española, que puede consultar gratuitamente via internet, le ofrece la respuesta. Consultándolo puede ver Vd. las definiciones actuales de los términos que plantea:

[Desembarazo](https://dle.rae.es/desembarazo):

> 2. m. Despejo, desenfado.

[Despejo](https://dle.rae.es/despejo?m=form):

> 3. m. Desembarazo, soltura en el trato o en las acciones.

Si lo que Vd. desea es conocer las definiciones más próximas en el tiempo al texto que cita, puede consultar el [Diccionario de Autoridades](http://web.frl.es/DA.html) (1726-1739), el primer diccionario que publicó la Real Academia Española e igualmente disponible gratuitamente a través de internet. En el podrá encontrar:

> **DESEMBARAZO**. s. m. Despejo, desenfado, libertad en el decir o hacer.

> **DESPEJO**. Vale tambien desenfado, desembarazo, donáire y brio.

con lo que puede apreciar que el significado de los vocablos apenas ha variado en el tiempo.

Los enlaces a dichos diccionarios y a otros que pueden ayudar a resolver este tipo de preguntas, los puede encontrar Vd. [aquí](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/23618/1674).